# sharepoint list column names not as created?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I created a list in office365 and getting list items with REST.

Column names of list is "Baslik,Icerik,Tarih"
but in response they seem; "Title,c53y,x4vu"(these are key of values, as you know resposne data in json format)

Title makes sense since I edited it. but why the others come from? and how can I set these key as origin list of columns in list?